# Ajax is not sending post data to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, file-upload

I'm trying to send long text (~200kb) through POST from JavaScript to PHP. I am using Ajax. Ajax function returns success, but $_POST is still empty. Code should get image from clipboard, convert it to base64 and send it to PHP.

I have tried to modify max post size, it's currently 200M.

**Javascript:**

```
document.onpaste = function(event){
    var items = (event.clipboardData || event.originalEvent.clipboardData).items;
    for (index in items) {
      var item = items[index];
      if (item.kind === 'file') {
        var blob = item.getAsFile();
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function(event){
          var res = event.target.result.toString();
          $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'index.php',
            data: ({file: res}),
            dataType: 'text',
            success: function(data) {
              console.log(res);
            }
          });
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
      }
    }
  }
```

**PHP:**

```php
if(isset($_POST["file"]))
{
  echo($_POST["file"]);
}
```

Comment: Check the network in the Google Chrome inspector to see whether the request was sent as a GET or POST request, it happens to me sometimes, i set the type to POST but it is sent as a GET request

Comment: Did you check in the browser tools if the POST payload is sent? If so in what format? Did you do `var_dump($_POST)`?

Comment: If you mean this, here is screenshot from Network > Headers tab - https://ctrlv.cz/shots/2019/04/28/gaZH.png

Comment: What's the output from your `console.log(res);` in the success callback?

Comment: That's successfully converted image to base64 format, here is screenshot: https://ctrlv.cz/shots/2019/04/28/QB3Z.png

Comment: What do you get if you change `console.log(res)` to `console.log(data)`? Do you get an empty output? If yes, then in your PHP code, before your if-statement, do: `var_dump($_POST); exit;` and check what `console.log(data);` outputs.

Comment: If i do so, I get whole code with base64 converted image in the end. https://ctrlv.cz/shots/2019/04/28/qdLa.png

Comment: It looks like your code actually does post the image successfully. However, you should either move your PHP code (the `if`-statement) to the top of your file (before any other output) and have an `exit;` last in the if-statement or better yet, move your PHP-code to it's own file. Right now, it looks like you're first outputting the HTML and then, after that, have your PHP-code. _All_ output from the requested page will be returned to your ajax callback.

Comment: Putting it to the top of file doesn't help. By moving it to another file, you mean this ```require_once('printer.php');``` in index, the original code in this file, and ```url: 'printer.php',``` in ajax? If so, still the same result.